# Probability Poisson random variable is larger than Exponential random variable

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Let $X \sim $ Exp$(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim$ Poisson$(\gamma)$ independence is assumed. Find $P(X<Y)$.

Would this be as follows:

$\displaystyle P(X < Y) = P(X < Y \mid Y = y)P(Y=y) = \frac{P(X < y, Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}P(Y=y) = P(X<y)P(Y=y)  \\ = \displaystyle \int_0^y \lambda e^{-\lambda x }dx \frac{e^{-\gamma}\gamma^y}{y!} \\ = \displaystyle(1-e^{-\lambda y})\frac{e^{-\gamma}\gamma^y}{y!}$

If this is incorrect an explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Minor error:  final expression should be $(1-e^{-\lambda y})...$  Major problem: $P(X\lt Y)\to 1$  as  $Y\to \infty$ doesn't hold.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I fixed the minor error. How do I account for the other issue? Also on reflection for the exponential part $y$ isn't required to be an integer but is for the Poisson so I need either the ceiling or floor applied to $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer cannot depend on $y$.

If you condition on $Y$ as you have done here, then your probability must be computed over all outcomes of $Y$.  So in particular, $$\Pr[X < Y] = \sum_{y=0}^\infty \Pr[X < Y \mid Y = y]\Pr[Y = y]$$ by the law of total probability.  Then $$\Pr[X < Y \mid Y = y] = \Pr[X < y] = 1 - e^{-\lambda y}$$ because $F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$.  It follows that $$\Pr[X < Y] = \sum_{y=0}^\infty (1 - e^{-\lambda y}) e^{-\gamma} \frac{\gamma^y}{y!}.$$  I leave it as an exercise for you to compute this sum.

---

Alternatively, if you condition on $X$, then $$\Pr[X < Y] = \int_{x=0}^\infty \Pr[X < Y \mid X = x]f_X(x) \, dx.$$  But this is a much less pleasant calculation since $$\Pr[X < Y \mid X = x] = \Pr[Y > x] = \sum_{y = \lfloor x \rfloor + 1}^\infty e^{-\gamma} \frac{\gamma^y}{y!}$$ and this is rather inconvenient to continue.

Comment: I get $\displaystyle (1-\exp(\frac{\gamma}{e^\lambda} - \gamma))$ as the result of the summation you have above.

Comment: Nice answer (+1).